How to start Angular frontend with C# backend
I have created a C# WinForms program with a WebView2 control to show an Angular user interface. The Angular frontend was created in Visual Studio Code and so far I used npm to serve the Angular frontend for development. But in the end the target is that my C# backend can start the Angular frontend by itself to show the user interface.
I already managed to do this by the following code, which simply starts the npm service in the background to make the frontend accessible for the WebView2 control:
string angularProjectPath = @"C:\workspace\software\mcinspect_cs\sources\Client\mcinspect\src";

// Set the command to start the Angular development server
string command = "npm start";

// Start the Angular development server process
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WorkingDirectory = angularProjectPath,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

g_uiProcess = Process.Start(psi);
g_uiProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);

But with this approach, the user of my program needs to have npm installed on his computer to use the software. I was wondering if there is an alternative way to provide a webserver by my C# project to serve the user interface. I saw there are some Angular Nugets available, but I'm not sure if I can use one of these to do this. I would prefer a solution where the serve of my frontend is fully integrated into my C# project to show the user interface. What is the right way to do it?
I used the code in the description to serve my frontend.

That doesn't make sense to me. Even if you want to present your Angular Frontend in a WebView in a WinForms app ( and I really don't know why you would want to do that ) - you'd need to host it on a server and your WinForms/WebView would basically just behave like any ol' Browser that accesses that Angular FE.

Did you choose the correct tech stack to begin with? If you have a "simple" GUI Program that doesn't actually depend on online Services, you probably would have wanted to go WinForms-Only, or WPF or similar. If it's a FrontEnd to an online (cloud?) Service, then why not just use Angular or Blazor or one of the gazillion other FE frameworks directly? Why the seemingly unneccessary wrapping?

The purpose of doing it in a WinForms App is to be able to close the backend service in case the Frontend is closed. If I only have a web browser and close the browser tab, then the backend would need to be closed separately. I wanted to avoid this.
Using C# for the backend was because we already have quite a number of Nugets for C# I wanted to use for that project.

Maybe you should define the terms here more clearly. What's a "Backend" to you?

Ok, "Backend" maybe is not the correct wording in this term. It is my "Program" which runs and makes use of an Angular FE.

Ok, so my first thought when I hear Backend and Frontend is some sort of Client/Server architecture, where "Server" might mean a remote Server. In this case, though,  we seem to be talking about something different. So, tell me if correct: It's supposed to be one Program, ideally one Process that gets started by the User and completely shut down when they quit, correct?

See 1 and 2.

Yes @Fildor, this is correct. The reason why I named it like this is: the previous version really was a backend service with a frontend client, but there was no use of a form to show the frontend.
